# In what circumstances would Hebrew 10:25 no longer apply?

Tags: ecclesiology

> not neglecting to meet together, as is the habit of some, but encouraging one another, and all the more as you see the Day drawing near.” ‭‭Hebrews‬ ‭10:25‬ ‭

The believer was encouraged to attend church gatherings, making a habit of neglecting or skipping church was not condoned.

What Biblical exceptions exist if any?

I assume imprisonment like Paul and Silas is one; being an apostle (sent with the gospel) is another; being bedridden like Peter’s mother is another. Would apostate congregations like Laodicea be another acceptable reason to not gather?

Comment: Nihil Sine Deo: You would attend another congregation that was spiritually rich.

Answer (score 1):

One keyword here is

Let us not neglect
ἐγκαταλείποντες (enkataleipontes)
Verb - Present Participle Active - Nominative Masculine Plural
Strong's Greek 1459: From en and kataleipo; to leave behind in some place, i.e. let remain over, or to **desert**.

Thayer's Greek Lexicon

> 1. to abandon, desert ...
> 2. to leave behind

Under some unavoidable circumstances, we can temporarily suspend meetings.

Another keyword here is "habit".

New International Version

> not giving up meeting together, as some are in the **habit** of doing

This is habitually neglecting or abandoning meetings as a permanent practice. This is not allowed.

I'd encourage one another as shownn in
Acts 2:42

> They devoted themselves to the apostles' teaching and to the fellowship, to the breaking of bread and to prayer.

Some form of participation/meeting/fellowship can always be practiced regularly, more or less.